# Why is my React component icon coming out as a typeof object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, icons, warnings

I'm trying to create a custom icon set defined from a css stylesheet but it throws the error "*Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: `<myIcon />`. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?*" I don't know why.

In myIcon.jsx, I've created a component `myIcon` that renders the custom icon in jsx form. `myIconsMap` creates an object map, where each key is the name of the icon and its value is a React component (made from `myIcon`).

```
//myIcon.jsx

import React from 'react';
import 'styles/fonts/customIcons.css';

const myIcons = ['randomIcon1', 'randomIcon2'];

const myIcon = props => {
  return <div className={`icon-${props.name}`} />;
};

const myIconsMap = myIcons.reduce((icons, iconName) => {
  icons[iconName] = <myIcon name={iconName} />;
  return icons;
}, {});

const randomIcon1 = myIconsMap.randomIcon1;
const randomIcon2 = myIconsMap.randomIcon2;

export {randomIcon1, randomIcon2};
```

But randomIcon1 and randomIcon2 both return typeof object, and I'm confused why because they both reference a React component (i.e. `). I think this is the problem; I need it to be a typeof function instead of object somehow before the browser can render it correctly.

After, I export my icons from myIcon.jsx to allIcons.jsx. This file is what renders the icons on the browser:

```
//allIcons.jsx

import {randomIcon1, randomIcon2} from './myIcon';

export const icons = {
  randomIcon1,
  randomIcon2  
}

const Icon = (name) => {
  const IconComponent =
    icons[`${name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${name.substring(1)}`];

  return <IconComponent />;
};
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `icons[iconName] = <myIcon name={iconName} />;` this renders the icon in place, so you get a rendered React node, which is an object.

Comment: How can I turn it into a function then?

Comment: Nicholas Tower already explained it well, notice the last line in his answer: `icons[iconName] = () => <myIcon name={iconName} />;`

Comment: @EmileBergeron sorry I misread his answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

```
icons[iconName] = <myIcon name={iconName} />;
```

This line doesn't create a new component. It renders the existing component, producing a react element. That element is a description of what to put on the page, which looks something like this:

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  type: MyIcon,
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: { name: iconName }
}
```

It is possible to use this to put stuff on the page, but not with a JSX tag like `<IconComponent />`. That would try to render it again, which can't happen since it has already been rendered. To use this element, you'd have to do:

```
const Icon = (name) => {
  const iconElement =
    icons[`${name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${name.substring(1)}`];

  return iconElement;
}
```

The other approach (and the one i'd recommend) is to create separate components for each icon. To do that, you just need to wrap your existing code in a function, thus turning it into a component.

```
icons[iconName] = () => <myIcon name={iconName} />;
```

Comment: I tried it but the element is still rendering as a typeof object even when I return iconElement (in your example) as a variable instead of a React component. Seems like it's still giving me the same output. (I also like your recommendation regarding creating separate components for each icon, but I'm trying to avoid that for this project since I'm going to have a ton of custom icons)

Comment: @123star45 creating a new component for each icon is the way to go. Pre-rendering JSX and caching its result object will only lead to more problems.